# How to add properties programmatically(just like adding key-value into application.properties)?

Tags: spring-boot

I have some common properties that every projects should set, such as

```
feign.hystrix.enabled=false
feign.httpclient.enabled=true
```

I don't want to repeatedly add these props in every project so I'm going to create an extra jar file containing `@Configruation` class. How to add properties in `@Configuration` class? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PropertySources**

You may load an `application.properties` from another jar this way:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:common.properties")
})
@Configuration
public class SomeJavaConfig {
}
```

You can find the reference in [Spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is
>   designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are
>   considered in the following order:
>
> ...
>
> 14. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.

**Spring-cloud-config**

I won't go in all the details, but another option is to use spring-cloud-config to define these properties in a git (using `spring-cloud-config-server`). Then, have your spring-boot application load the application.properties using `spring-cloud-config-client` directly from git.

Check this:

- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/